# How is segmentation more secure than paging?

Tags: operating-system, memory-segmentation, computer-science-theory

This question occurred to me while i was reading memory management in Galvin?
There were two parts i didn't understand.
Look the first one is a direct question from Galvin.
Answer which i didn't understand was 
"Since segmentation is based on a logical division of memory rather than a physical
one, segments of any size can be shared with only one entry in the segment tables of
each user. With paging there must be a common entry in the page tables for each page that is shared"
1)Why it is easier to share reentrant code in segmentation?
2)Is segmentation more secure than paging?Why

Comment: if you could just point out the mistake before downvoting

Comment: Some of the reasons why someone downvoted your question are explained in the tooltip of the downvote button "_This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_" and other frequent reasons are listed in http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. I don't know what are the reasons in this case, my bet would be the effort part. e.g. segment of any size is represented by 1 entry that needs to be shared, while  memory of 56 pages needs 56 page table entries to be shared. 1 < 56 (see http://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table vs http://wiki.osdev.org/Page_Frame_Allocation)

Answer (score 0):

I've never read the Galvin book but a lot of questions here asking why absurd things are true and cite that is a source.

1. It is not easier to share reentrant code using segments rather than paging.

IN a paging system, the share code can be mapped to different processes simply by adding section to the page table. It's a very straight forward process.

2. Segmentation is not more security than paging.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that segmentation is more secure than paging because of its homogenous nature. You can tailor the protection and access mechanism based on which segment of data you are dealing with. In paging, this is not possible.